# FB.ui method share does not return callback when using Facebook Mobile Browser

Tags: callback, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     FB.ui({
         method: "share",
         href: href,
         ref: ref,
         hashtag: hashtag,
         quote: quote
     }, function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         if (response !== undefined && !response.error_code) {
             return resolve(response);
         }

         return reject(response);
     });
});
```

Nothing happens after the user hits the share button on the facebook mobile browser...

The callback function isn't triggered.

How to reproduce:
Shared my site on facebook, clicked the link that came up on the facebook app. That opens up the Facebook Mobile Browser and click the button that triggers the javascript I've mentioned. The share dialog opens up above this, I click share, it goes away and nothing else happens.

Comment: Did you get this working ?

Comment: No. Facebook did get back to me. They said that confirmation will not be reliable if they're using the facebook mobile browser because the app opens up to carry out the sharing process. Getting back to the browser from where the share was triggered isn't possible.